# Wireshark Dissector: How to decode variable length field

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I'm new to coding 'c' Wireshark dissector, so I have a pretty basic question regarding the way to decode a field which has a variable length, meaning at some packets it can be 1byte and in other packets it can be 8 bytes.

Is there a pattern to handle this? what the best way? examples would be awesome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You specify the length when you add the item to the tree.  For example, in the most general case you can use `proto_tree_add_item()`, declared in [`proto.h`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/proto.h;h=e749979b8ec0c36869a8b39113b04d2740d148e6;hb=HEAD#l1079) as:

`WS_DLL_PUBLIC proto_item *
proto_tree_add_item(proto_tree *tree, int hfindex, tvbuff_t *tvb,
                    const gint start, gint length, const guint encoding);`

So in one case:

```
proto_tree_add_item(tree, hfindex, tvb, start, 1, encoding);
```

... and in the other case:

```
proto_tree_add_item(tree, hfindex, tvb, start, 8, encoding);
```

The Wireshark code base contains many dissectors and thus many examples you can you use to help you, so feel free to browse the code as well as the various README's.

Answer (score 0):

As described in Christopher Maynard post. To specify protocol item use `proto_tree_add_item()` method. If this item has variable data length and this length is part of received packet, it can be extracted from tvb buffer passed by dissector.

Example:

```
static int dissect_foo(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree, void* data)
{
    gint msglen, offset = 0;

    proto_item *ti = proto_tree_add_item(tree, proto_foo, tvb, 0, -1, ENC_NA);
    proto_tree *foo_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(ti, ett_foo);

    //first item - fixed length - byte contains next item length
    proto_tree_add_item(foo_tree, hf_foo_len, tvb, offset, 1, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
    //extract value from buffer
    msglen = tvb_get_guint8(tvb, offset++);
    //second item - variable length
    proto_tree_add_item(foo_tree, hf_foo_name, tvb, offset, msglen, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
    offset += msglen;
    ...
```